# File-to-fully qualified class name function

Tags: functional-programming, scala

My instincts are telling me a seasoned Scala programmer will find my code less than optimal. As will no doubt be obvious, I'm a Java guy who has just started in with Scala. Is there a more 'functional' way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

```
/**
   * takes a file object and returns a string representing the fully qualified
   * class name represented by that file.
   *
   * @param file
   * @return string representation of the fully qualified class name
   */
  def makeFqClassName(file: File): String = {
    // pull out the file name - we'll use this for our class name
    val fNameNoExtS = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName)

    // extract only the path
    val fPathOnlyS =
      file.getPath.substring(0, file.getPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator))

    // create a list of the path name, minus the delimiter
    val fPathDelimList: List[String] = fPathOnlyS.split("/").toList

    // truncate the list to include on the class name info
    val fqNameList: List[String] =
      fPathDelimList.drop(fPathDelimList.lastIndexOf("solutions"))

    // convert the list to a string representation of a class name and return
    // to caller
    fqNameList.mkString(".") + "." + fNameNoExtS
  }
```

Expected input: .java file object where the file name and the class name enclosed in the file are the same.

> Sp01.scala

Expected output: fully qualified class name:

> solutions.working_with_lists.Sp01

Note that if we were working with one of the problems from another group, the class name would be something like:

> solutions.arithmetic.Sp31

The reason for all this is that I'm new to Scala and working my way through the [99 Scala problems set](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/). This method is part of a test runner that trolls through the project files, picks up solution files, then uses reflection to instantiate an instance of the solution class and executes its solver method. This way I can organize the project files in a way that makes sense - in a way that matches the manner in which the problem set is structured - as well as work on whatever problem I want to work on while simultaneously giving me the freedom to reorganize the package structure w/o having to refactor the runner code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and why is `"solutions"` a special case?

Comment: @200_success I'm working my way through the 99 scala problems - this is part of the test runner (see http://preview.tinyurl.com/kyqc55h for the full code). the top-level package name is 'solutions', which is why that's special. because I'm coding and running the tests as I go, the test runner traverses the project directories and searches for files that conform to a spec, creates an instance of the class embodied in the file, and executes the solution/test code. this utility allows me to take a file path/file name and turn it into a fully qualified class name to use in the reflection code.

Comment: Could you include an input and expected output?

Comment: requested info is contained in the update. also - know that this is part of a test runner that I've written as part of my endeavor to solve the entire 99 scala problems set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current assumption is that the string returned by `file.getPath` is going to look something like `..\solutions\some-parent-dir\some-scala-file.scala`

If this is the case then you can try the following function:

```
def makeFqClassName(file: File): String = {
  val fileName :: _ = file.getName.split('.').toList
  val upDir :: upUpDir :: _ = file.getParent.split(File.separator(0)).toList.reverse
  s"$upUpDir.$upDir.$fileName"
}
```

I've introduced a smidgen of strange syntax just to show you a possibility. As a way of explaining what is going on, consider that the following are *functionally* equivalent:

```
  val foo :: _ = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
  val goo = List(0, 1, 2, 3).head
```

From the POV of *operations* performed they're unequivalent. 
`foo` is defined from the result of a pattern match that discards the tail of the list. `goo` as you know is the result of the invocation of the `head` method. (I suppose it could be the case that the compiler is smart enough to translate a pattern match on a list that only takes the head of the list into an invocation of the head method, but lets just ignore that for now :^) And a final example:

```
val a :: b :: c :: d :: ez = ('a' to 'z').toList
```

Here `a` , `b` , `c` , and `d`  are assigned the expected character values and `ez` is a list consisting of the characters `e` through `z`.

If I've misunderstood what your asking for please let me know and I'll update this accordingly.

Comment: w000000000t! t/y for this, it was exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to play with this a bit today and see how it jives with the rest of the runner. cheers, mate!